# How can I make Plone portal registries find and cook new-style static resources?

Tags: resources, plone, diazo

All JS I register with an id such as `++theme++mythemename/js/myscript.js` gives me the following error on `portal_javascripts`: **`(resource not found or not accessible)`**

I know the id is correct because I can access `localhost/mysite/++theme++mythemename/js/myscript.js` (even if Diazo is disabled).

If development mode is on the resource gets delivered on the final HTML. However on production mode cooking process fails silently. Or almost. Besides getting a different cachekey than the one showed on `portal_javascripts/manage_jsComposition`, I see the following error message by accessing the cooked file:

**`/* XXX ERROR -- access to '++theme++mythemename/js/myscript.js' not authorized */`**

Any hints on how to deal with those? Or will I really need to leave them uncooked?

Comment: maybe your resourcefolder is registered for a layer that is not active when you access the zmi but when you access the themed site.

try removing the layer attribute from your registration to check whether this might be the issue here

Comment: My resourcefolder isn't registered for a specific layer. It's just this: [<plone:static directory="static" name="mytheme" type="theme" />](https://github.com/observatoriogenero/observatorio.tema/blob/master/src/observatorio/tema/configure.zcml#L36) (this link leads to full source)

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'm pretty sure I used theme resources with resource registries before.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a browser:resourceDirectory instead of a plone:static ?

```
 <browser:resourceDirectory
    name="yourJsFolder"
    directory="yourJsFolder"
    layer=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
    />
```

and calling your js with :

> ++resource++yourJsFolder/yourJsFile.js

Comment: This does work. However I won't mark your answer as accepted since it's more like a workaound and not a complete solution because I'm unable to edit those resources TTW: they don't show up neither at `portal_resources` (ZMI) nor at new ACE Editor in `++theme++ mythemename/@@theming-controlpanel-mapper`. I wonder if that's some kind of bug within `p.a.theming`...

Answer (score 0):

i added your [observatorio.tema](https://github.com/observatoriogenero/observatorio.tema) package to an existing plone 4.1 buildout and added a random js file to the js registry (positioned after collapsibleformfields.js so it gets properly cooked)

GS export looks like:

```
<javascript authenticated="False" cacheable="True" compression="safe"
    conditionalcomment="" cookable="True" enabled="True" expression=""
    id="++theme++observatorio/js/ui.js" inline="False" insert-after="collapsibleformfields.js"/>
```

no error in portal_jacascripts and the javascript file is included in /jquery-cachekey-e7bee35d43da7a91eb29c6586dcbd396.js

did you add cacheable="False" and cookable="False" for testing purposes?
https://github.com/observatoriogenero/observatorio.tema/blob/master/src/observatorio/tema/profiles/default/jsregistry.xml#L373

since plone:static internally is a resourceDirectory both should and do work with resourceregistries.

maybe there is some other code in your buildout that re-registers another (empty) directory for the same name (observatorio)?

Comment: Yes, I added cacheable="False" and cookable="False" for testing purposes. Actually even enabled="False" since that id wasn't being cooked I was including the JS directly through `static/index.html` (not using the ones registered in the portal registries). I'll repeat your steps and doublecheck for registered empty static directories (even though I think that should have raised an Exception).